# cross browser css styles-suggestions

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have a couple of issues with CSS in IE 11 and mozila which works well in Chrome.

1. Border-Radius issue - works in chrome but not in IE 11

   ```
   table, td, th {
      border-radius: 25px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
   }
   ```
2. Style sheets applied are working fine in Chrome and IE 11 but not in Firefox.
3. Tables that are aligned properly in chrome are a little misplaced in IE 11.

What is the best way to fix all these issues. I read quite a few articles on these. I unchecked the compatibility view settings(intranet) option which was one suggestion in an article. But nothing seems to be working out well.

Any leads ?

Comment: Provide full code what you've tried since, then get the help you will.

Comment: try Vendor Extension Prefixes for IE as -ms-

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the code below?

```
  table, td, th {
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; /*ff*/
    -ms-border-radius: 25px; /*ie11*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
```

Comment: Tried it. But not working ! Still the border radius thing is broken and not proper.

Comment: It shows a red line under the -ms-border-radius: 25px in the console window of IE11.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have add this line in head and `-ms-border-radius: 11px;` works in ie.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```